# I installed Android Studio on a new Windows 11 pc and now the projects that were created on my old pc don't load correctly on the new pc

Tags: android-studio, installation

I am pretty new to java and Android Studio and have run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve and am hoping that someone can help me with it or direct me to someone who can.

I just got a new pc that has windows 11 and I installed java development kit 21 and then installed Android Studio Giraffe.  I edited the system environmental variables also.
I started a simple new project and everything went well.  Setup a virtual device and a physical phone, both working just like on my old pc.

Then I tried to open an old project that had been created on the old pc (windows10 and Android Studio Electric Eel).  Here is a screen shot of what came up...What is causing this?  Not only is the file structure scrambled, there isn't a run/debug configuration either.

I tried un-stalling and re-installing everything, but the results were the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30GNq.png)

I tried Googling this problem but didn't find a similar issue with a solution.
One thing I did notice is that the path on Windows 11 creates a user folder for you and it's not a simple thing to rename it. So that user folder is a different name than the user folder on the old pc.  I thought that if you brought an old project to a new pc, the old project would load using the settings for the new pc.  Is that an incorrect assumption on my part?

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated,
Jim